# Changing Subsection Marker

Tags: sectioning

So, I am using the following to change the subsection enumeration scheme: 
`\usepackage{titlesec}` with `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\S}`.

And, this is great, but I would like to add an numeral to this. I want it to look like `(SUBSECTION SYMBOL) NUMBER`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthesubsection\thesubsection
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\S\svthesubsection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section{my section}
\subsection{my subsection}
\subsubsection{my subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Nice profile pic, lol.

Comment: I was wondering, what does `\let\svthesubsection\thesubsection` do?  I have never seen that.

Comment: @phatty Oh, yeah.  I had almost forgot the connection.

Comment: @phatty The `\let` makes a copy of `\thesubsection` macro and places it in a new macro `\svthesubsection`.  This will help avoid a self-referential infinite loop that would otherwise occur if I tried to redefine `\thesubsection` in terms of itself.